# Overriding a JS variable by clicking a link in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to create a animations demo.

**In HTML markup, here's my script;**

```
<script>
    /* Set your slide animation */
    var $setAnimation = 'slideInLeft';

    /* Set carousel slide delays (7.5s is default) */
    var $carouselDelay = 7500;
</script>
```

By setting a new variable name in $setAnimation, i can change to slide animations. But instead, i am trying to create a mini panel. So when user click to animation name, it will override to $setAnimation and new animation effect will be dynamically applied.

Here's my code for it but it doesnt work.

```
<a id="animGlitch">Change to Glitch</a>
```

And JS

```
var x = document.getElementById("animGlitch");
x.addEventListener("click", changeAnim);

function changeAnim()
{
    var setAnimation = 'glitch';
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: All `changeAnim` does right now is declare and initialize a local function variable - that variable is destroyed and forgotten about once your function returns. This means `setAnimation` is really not being used at all.

Comment: You are setting a local variable `var setAnimation` within your `changeAnim` function call: that is, it doesn't effect your global variable you've already defined.

If you want to update that, just reference the previously created variable that is available from the outside scope. That is `function changeAnim() { setAnimation = 'glitch'; }`. See this [MDN Article on variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) for more information.

Comment: Have you thought about using an attribute on the click element to indicate what animation should occur? Then if someone changes the animation, you just change the attribute value to the new animation.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `setAnimation` locally in the js snippet, when you should be changing the global variable.

```
var x = document.getElementById("animGlitch");
x.addEventListener("click", changeAnim);

function changeAnim()
{
    $setAnimation = 'glitch';
}
```

I see now @romellem mentioned this in the comments as well.